# When should I use GoldParse when training NER?

Tags: spacy

When looking at example code for training NER with SpaCy, I see GoldParse used sometimes and sometimes not.

```
TRAINING_DATA = [
    ("How to preorder the iPhone X", {'entities': [(20, 28, 'GADGET')]})
    #Lots of other things
]
```

(Then common stuff, adding labels to the NER pipe, disabling other pipes, etc.)

Then I see two approaches:

```
for iteration in range(10):

    random.shuffle(TRAINING_DATA)
    losses = {}

    for text, annotations in TRAINING_DATA:
        doc = nlp.make_doc(text)
        entity_offsets = annotations["entities"]
        gold = GoldParse(doc, entities=entity_offsets)
        nlp.update([doc], [gold], drop=0.5, sgd=optimizer, losses=losses)
        print('Losses with gold', losses)
```

OR

```
for iteration in range(10):

    random.shuffle(TRAINING_DATA)
    losses = {}

    batches = minibatch(TRAINING_DATA, size=compounding(4.0, 32.0, 1.001))
    for batch in batches:
        texts, annotations = zip(*batch)
        nlp.update(texts, annotations, drop=0.5, sgd=optimizer, losses=losses)
        print('Losses without gold', losses)
```

What purpose (if any) is GoldParse serving in this example? The loss outputs are a bit different, but I don't feel like I'm really understanding what the difference is.

Answer (score 0):

They should be identical underneath. If you comment out the shuffle, I would expect the losses to be identical.